# I'm stuck at this "Windows Update Standalone Installer" can you help me continue the update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I've been trying to get this to work for days on end. I've reset my computer, redownloaded this update *KB2592687* and waited hours for it to update. Does anyone know a way I can get past the "windows Update Standalone Installer" portion of the process? And if you could be **as detailed as humanly possible** about it, i'd appreciate that a lot. Since most tutorials tend to not be very specific with how I do everything and where I go to do these things.

Edit: also i already have Service Pack 1

Comment: Can you give us more details about the exact steps you are doing and what you are seeing at each step? When you say "I've reset my computer", what does that mean exactly? Why are you trying to manually install this update rather than using Windows Update? Installing the System Readiness Tool helped some. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6eabc26b-5a66-4842-82f1-fb82bc6e82fc/windows-update-kb2592687-fails-to-install

Comment: I've tried Windows Update but it doesnt change anything, the KB stays at 0%, and for the steps I took here's what I did: i went to Windows update, found the updates that I needed and tried to allow the system to install them, nothing happened like before so I went to microsoft to find out the problem. They gave me this KB update to manually install and I've been waiting here for hours. I reset my computer to see if it'd update it self but to no avail. And I'm downloading the readiness tool, that's the issue I'm having. It wont install it just says "searching for updates on this computer".

Comment: Just FYI, I've had computers say "Searching for updates" for 8-12 hours+ before finally finishing, listing them and allowing me to continue (especially on computers that haven't been updated in years). Try letting it search overnight. Same with installing updates... let it run overnight as long as the mouse isn't frozen and it's giving you some feedback (progress bar, text, spinning hourglass, etc.) it's better than powering it off and potentially introducing corruption.

Comment: Alright I'll let it update over night

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if other people know or mean the same.

Lately Microsoft released a rollup which might be installed separetly and not thru the Update-service.

If you have already SP1 you may download and install first:

https: //support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020369

choosing your version.

Then the rollup [this](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2016/05/windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x64_2dafb1d203c8964239af3048b5dd4b1264cd93b9.msu) for 64bit or [this](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2016/05/windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x86_ba1ff5537312561795cc04db0b02fbb0a74b2cbd.msu) for 32bit.

If the links doesn't work you may download it from:

http: //catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=3125574

using an Active-X able Browser like Internet Explorer.

Comment: i went t the catalog.update link and i installed it, now something has popped up showing me the update I need, but it doesnt do anything, I clicked the name and it only tells me what the update does. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Did you download this Update for Windows 7 (KB3125574) or this Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3125574) ?

Comment: If you're already updating something else wait first for it.

Comment: Alright i'll wait.